# React - modify props asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

Through using Redux, my component receives a data array in the props. My goal is to modify those data points asynchronously once the component has them, like following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
   newProps.myData.forEach ( d => {
       axios.get(....).then (res => { d.property = res.data) });
   })
}
```

I am also using `react-bootstrap-table-2` to display `this.props.myData`. However, the update is never reflected in the table. If I change it synchronously like

`componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) { newProps.myData.forEach( d => d.property = 1 ) }`

then it is shown in the table. How can I achieve the asynchronous update?

Comment: use  `redux-thunk`

Comment: props are supposed to be immutable. In particular, modifying props in place will not trigger a rerender

Comment: In redux world you are supposed to fire an action with payload once your api call returns

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux, the way you update your state should be dispatching an action to your reducer. You can dispatch an action to your reducer by providing `dispatch` to your component, then calling your action by calling `dispatch(updateTable(newData)`

```
// tableActions.js
function updateTable(newData) {
  return {
     type: 'UPDATE_TABLE',
     newData: newData
  }
}

// tableReducer.js

function tableReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TABLE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        tableData: action.newData
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

You will need something like redux thunk for this to work